# Analytical Badge?

Tags: support, faq-content, badges

I know going on a badge-quest is probably a tad bit cheesy.  But this one's been bugging me.  I feel like by now I should have read all the sections of the FAQ - so recently I made a deliberate effort to go back through it, skimming areas I knew I'd already read deeply, and making sure I read anything that seemed new to me.

But it's been more than a few days and I haven't been awarded the Analytical badge.  How can one tell what one's missed on the FAQ?  I'd happily catch up - since as a user with a lot of privs, it's a very, very good idea for me to be deeply clueful about the FAQ guidance!

Comment: Did you click every link in the sidebar (all the sections)? I think that's the main thing that counts actually.

Comment: @Rarity - it worked!

Comment: Cheesy? You mean my [failed quest yesterday](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/551/wheres-my-vox-populi-badge) for the Vox Populi badge was cheesy? ;-)

Comment: I had the same problem and curiosity hah.

Answer (score 7):

FYI - final answer - Rarity was totally correct in his comment above.  I had to click every item in the sidebar.  I strongly suspect I had read every section - possibly by scrolling and clicking to expand sections.  But the badge actually came through when I had clicked every item in the sidebar, using the sidebar only.

It worked the same for both main and meta.

The nerdy tester in me wonders if that's really the functionality we want for this - no matter how someone reads the FAQ, the resulting knowledge they get is the same.  But then there's always some technical details that make other types of implementation tricky...

Comment: You've read the FAQ right? Probably a long time ago, and now that you've spent time working towards the honorable quest for the Analytical badge, you're most likely a bit more familiar with the different sections, especially since you succeeded! If you needed to, let's say, quote the promotion section of the faq, my bet is that you could probably find it a lot quicker than you could before. :)  Now, this isn't just information you've read, but a document that you're very familiar with should you need to find the information quickly! The point is, the badge works. :)